# Limit of relation sums of exponential functions

Tags: limits

Help to solve example:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{7^{3n-1}+3^n}}{3^n+4 \cdot 7^{n+1}}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.**

For all $n \in \mathbb N$

$$
\frac{\sqrt[3]{7^{3n-1}+3^n}}{3^n+4*7^{n+1}}=\frac{7^n}{7^n}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{7}+\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n}}{28+\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{7}+\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n}}{28+\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n}
$$

and $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^n = ?$

Comment: Of course, thanks